# DataGridRow Does not Select on ConextMenuOpening when DataGridTemplateColumn with TextBox is Used

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DataGrid` with template columns using TextBoxes. These TextBoxes have a custom `ContextMenu`  assigned through stylings. The problem is that when I "right click" in one of the template column TextBoxes to open the context menu, the `DataGridRow` does not select when the `ContextMenu` opens. It works with left click though (`TextBox` focuses and the `DataGridRow` selects).

```xml
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="SD" Width="30" MaxWidth="30" MinWidth="30">
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                          <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                      </DataTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I've tried other solutions on here, but they aren't quite right for my scenario.

I have to assign direct to the textbox context menu, and I have to use template columns (the textboxes are actually custom textboxs that handle money). How can I bubble up/not handle the right click so that the `DataGrid` row will select when the `ContextMenu` is opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I bubble up/not handle the right click so that the DataGrid row will select when the ContextMenu is opened?

For example by handling the `GotKeyboardFocus` and find the parent `DataGridRow` element in the visual tree using a helper method:

```
private void TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    DataGridRow dataGridRow = FindParent<DataGridRow>(textBox);
    if (dataGridRow != null)
        dataGridRow.IsSelected = true;
}

private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null)
        return null;

    T parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  Header="SD" Width="30" MaxWidth="30" MinWidth="30">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Description, Mode=OneWay}" GotKeyboardFocus="TextBox_GotKeyboardFocus" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```